# The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plugin (0.7.3)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I tried importing one of my old project(written in Windows) to Android Studio (Now mac).

However, I get following error from Gradle:

> Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing,
>   debugging) will not work properly.

On the event log it says:

> Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android
>   Gradle plug-in (0.7.3).
>
> Version 0.9.0 introduced incompatible changes in the build language.
>   Please read the migration guide to learn how to update your project.
>   Open migration guide, fix plug-in version
>   and re-import project

Here is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

Can anybody point the probable solution?

Answer (score 0):

What the error message says it that your version of Android Studio requires a newer version of the Gradle Android plugin than 0.7.3 (see `buildscript` block). Bump it to 0.9.0 and try to import the project again.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. But now I'm getting this error: Error:com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30 (double-click here to find usages.)

Comment: Did you check out the migration guide, as mentioned in the earlier error message?